# CodeMirror on Custom Widget Textarea

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm currently using this code within my plugin on a custom widgets textarea to enable codemirror.

```
(function ($) {
        $(document).ready( function(){
              var coinmedi_es_<?php echo $wid_id; ?> = wp.codeEditor.defaultSettings ? _.clone( wp.codeEditor.defaultSettings ) : {};
                coinmedi_es_<?php echo $wid_id; ?>.codemirror = _.extend(
                    {},
                    coinmedi_es_<?php echo $wid_id; ?>.codemirror,
                    {
                        mode: 'htmlmixed',
                        lineNumbers: true,
                        indentUnit: 2,
                        tabSize: 2,
                        autoRefresh:true

                    }
                );
            var cm_editor_<?php echo $wid_id; ?> = wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>') , coinmedi_es_<?php echo $wid_id; ?> );

            $(document).on('keyup', '.CodeMirror-code', function(){
                $('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>').html(cm_editor_<?php echo $wid_id; ?>.codemirror.getValue());
                $('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>').trigger('change');
            });

        });
})(jQuery);
```

Everything is working fine for HTML but when I try to add javascript eg.

```
<script> alert('1') </script>
```

It accepts the javascript and highlights as it should but when I click the save button nothing is posted for this textarea. When I remove the javascript it saves as it should. Where am I going wrong, I can't seem to pinpoint why it's not saving. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Update method

```
$instance['ad-code'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['ad-code'] ) ) ? $new_instance['ad-code'] : '';
```

Comment: What's the update method of your widget?

Comment: Added the line for the update method, problem is it doesn't get that far because the data that is sent is blank on the field whenever JS is added, if I remove the JS it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came down to using `.html` and injecting html directly into Codemirror, specifically this line:

```
$('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>').html(cm_editor_<?php echo $wid_id; ?>.codemirror.getValue());
```

Changing this to `.text` corrected the issue by encoding the html / js

```
$('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>').text(cm_editor_<?php echo $wid_id; ?>.codemirror.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try :

1) to wrap javascript in `CDATA` ?

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    alert('1');
//]]>
</script>
```

2) change `mode` to `javascript` (instead of `mode: 'htmlmixed'`)

Comment: Still clears unfortunately.

Comment: @Second2None I've updated the answer, with second possible solution.

Comment: Sorry mate no luck, it accepts basic javascript(var test = 'test';) but not imported scripts or html (which is why I was using htmlmixed). I assume I'm missing some sort of javascript check / function that is clearing codemirror on possible disallowed html / js. I'm just not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for such a thing. This can be useful for you:

https://wpreset.com/add-codemirror-editor-plugin-theme/